# In cmake, what is a "project"?

Tags: cmake

This question is about the `project` command and, by extension, what the *concept* of a `project` means in cmake. I genuinely don't understand what a `project` is,  and how it differs from a `target` (which I do understand, I think).

I had a look at the [cmake documentation for the `project`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/project.html) command, and it says that the `project` command does this:

> Set a name, version, and enable languages for the entire project.

It should go without saying that using the word *project* to define *project* is less than helpful.

Nowhere on the page does it seem to explain what a project actually *is* (it goes through some of the things the command *does*, but doesn't say whether that list is exclusive or not). The [cmake.org examples](http://www.cmake.org/examples/) take us through a basic build setup, and while it uses the `project` keyword it also doesn't explain what it does or means, at least not as far as I can tell.

What is a *project*? And what does the `project` command do?

Comment: This is Cmake documentation hell, you are welcome.
And it got much worse the 4 years since you asked this question.

Comment: CMake tries to fix a mess with another organized mess.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

A project logically groups a number of targets (that is, libraries, executables and custom build steps) into a self-contained collection that can be built on its own.

In practice that means, if you have a `project` command in a `CMakeLists.txt`, you should be able to run CMake from that file and the generator should produce something that is buildable. In most codebases, you will only have a single project per build.

Note however that you may nest multiple projects. A top-level project may include a subdirectory which is in turn another self-contained project. In this case, the `project` command introduces additional scoping for certain values. For example, the [`PROJECT_BINARY_DIR`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/PROJECT_BINARY_DIR.html) variable will always point to the root binary directory of the current project. Compare this with [`CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_BINARY_DIR.html), which always points to the binary directory of the *top-level* project. Also note that certain generators may generate additional files for projects. For example, the Visual Studio generators will create a `.sln` solution file for each subproject.

Use sub-projects if your codebase is very complex and you *need users to be able to build certain components in isolation*. This gives you a very powerful mechanism for structuring the build system. Due to the increased coding and maintenance overhead required to make the several sub-projects truly self-contained, I would advise to only go down that road if you have a real use case for it. Splitting the codebase into different targets should always be the preferred mechanism for structuring the build, while sub-projects should be reserved for those rare cases where you really need to make a subset of targets self-contained.

Comment: Hello, ComicsSansMS. _ if you have a project command in a CMakeLists.txt, you should be able to run CMake from that file and the generator should produce something that is buildable._ I also see some projects which use _project_ commond for head-only library. What's the role of _project_ plays here?

Comment: @陳力 Besides the fact that the header-only library does not actually build anything, it is still the same as for other libraries: The call to `project` should indicate a self-contained collection that does not depend on anything from higher up in the source tree. Of course, it is even easier to accidentally get this wrong for header-only libraries, so it might be that your particular header-only library does not actually do this, in which case the additional project command will be utterly useless.