# How do I change CMakes output sln for MVS?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

CMake(3.9.1) is working perfectly except for one issue.  The last project I build in the root CMakeLists is used for the final output project sln name.  I have a root CMakeLists that will execute other CMakeLists for the other projects.  For example, the root CMakeLists does a project("SomeName") and that "SomeName" will be the output sln.

I was wondering if I can override this to always use a custom name, rather than the last project that was built.  (so a project's sln is not some helper library!)

Thank You!

Comment: Isn't the solution name select by the root `project()` command given name? Do you have a `project()` call in the root `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: Yes, I do. Currently I have 3.  But this will grow!

Comment: Three `project()` calls in one `CMakeLists.txt` file? Why would you do that? One `project()` call is totally sufficient.

Comment: BAH!  I thought I needed a project to name each project!  Thank you!  :)  Make an answer and Ill accept!

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26878379/in-cmake-what-is-a-project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer*

The Visual Studio solution name is defined by the name given in your root `CMakeLists.txt` call to `project()`.

And *one* `project()` call in the root `CMakeLists.txt` file is totally sufficient. I thought you would also get a warning if you make multiple `project()` calls in one `CMakeLists.txt`.

**Reference**

- [CMake - setting Visual Studio solution name](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-September/039844.html)

Comment: Thank you. Does `project()` command have other usages other than giving the name to the `sln` file?